# Google Drive REST in iOS

Tags: ios, rest, api, google-drive-api, drive

My question is rather simple.
After integrating Google Drive REST API I could finally download files from my Google Drive.SO I have followed this example 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads
Everything is working fine,and in console I get the information that the file is downloaded. So here is the question:where  it goes,to which folder ? What is the path to where the file is saved?
And how do I set the necessary save path if I need to save a file to iOS Documents folder?

```
NSString *fileId = @"0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M";

GTLRQuery *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesGet queryForMediaWithFileId:fileId];
[driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                     GTLRDataObject *file,
                                                     NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Downloaded %lu bytes", file.data.length);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

I a developing for iOS 10 and an above and as I read the infrmation:NOTE: Because NSURLConnection is deprecated as of iOS 9 and OS X 10.11, this class has been superseded by GTMSessionFetcher.I should use either code provided by google(posted above ) or GTMSessionFetcher.I am using code from google.But Will be thankful is someone will help me solve my problem with both (google and GTMSessionFetcher) variants.

Comment: Which way do you request this REST API? NSURLSession? AFNetworking?

Comment: I am using original code form google,I have updated the question, maybe it will help!

Comment: I've updated my answer for your case, please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD: For Google API Client lib**

`GTLRDataObject` has `data` property which contains raw bytes of your file.  It is enough to safe your file using standard iOS methods.

There is also `contentType` property which is a string with [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) of the file. You probably want to store this information somewhere along with the path to saved `data`, it will help you to properly display what kind of file (image/song/text) it is, as well as use it when you decode/open/read saved data to present actual information.

```
GTLRQuery *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesGet queryForMediaWithFileId:fileId];
[driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                 GTLRDataObject *file,
                                                 NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Downloaded %lu bytes", file.data.length);

        // Here is where you take these bytes and save them as file to any location you want (typically your Documents folder)
        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        [file.data writeToURL:documentsDirectoryURL atomically:YES];

        // Now you can store the url/path of the saved file somewhere along with the MIME type string (maybe new class or structure describing the file in your app)
        MyFile *file = [[MyFile alloc] initWithFilePath:[documentsDirectoryURL path] mimeType:contentType];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

See [CocoaDocs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/GoogleAPIClientForREST/1.0.1/Classes/GTLRDataObject.html#//api/name/data) for `GTLRDataObject` reference.

---

**Generic version: using iOS SDK**

If you use `NSURLSession`, it has delegate method which you use to move file from temporary location to anywhere you need.

**Obj-C**

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {
    // Use `location` to move your data to Documents directory or wherever else
}
```

**Swift**

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    // Use `location` to move your data to Documents directory or wherever else
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I really appreciate your answer, but I have no Idea what to write instaed of "MyFile" in the line of allocation.Also,what I am trying to download is a *.db3 file which doesnt have a mimeType.(At least google doesn't provide necessary mimeType for *.db3 files).Maybe you could suggest something?